# Treating Blanks as Zeros within a Salesforce formula

Tags: lightning-experience, formula, reporting, formula-field

I have this formula created to work out the number of days between created date and the closed date, but also this takes away the time which the opportunity was sat with a broker.

However, I have noticed, that if any of these 2 fields are 'Blank' there is an issue as it returns no result whatsoever.

I have tried using the **"Blank Value"** function, but it keeps providing me with different errors depending on what I input.

When I try and use **'0'** as the substitute expression, it tells me; **"incorrect parameter type for function 'BLANKVALUE()'. Expected DateTime, received Number"**

I then tried putting in a default date instead, but the error i get after this is **"Error when encoding row-level formula: Syntax error. Missing ')'**

The formula as it works now which i need to change is as below:

> (DATETIMEVALUE(CUST_LAST_UPDATE) -
> Scheme_Referral__c.Scheme_Created_Date_Time__c) -
> (Scheme_Referral__c.Date_Broker_Response__c -
> Scheme_Referral__c.Date_Requested_Info__c)

The formula i tried to add blank value and zeros is below:

> (DATETIMEVALUE(CUST_LAST_UPDATE) -
> Scheme_Referral__c.Scheme_Created_Date_Time__c) -
> (BLANKVALUE(Scheme_Referral__c.Date_Broker_Response__c,0)) -
> (BLANKVALUE(Scheme_Referral__c.Date_Requested_Info__c,0))

The formula i tried with the default dates is below:

> (DATETIMEVALUE(CUST_LAST_UPDATE) -
> Scheme_Referral__c.Scheme_Created_Date_Time__c) -
> (BLANKVALUE(Scheme_Referral__c.Date_Broker_Response__c, 01/01/2023
> 12:00)) - (BLANKVALUE(Scheme_Referral__c.Date_Requested_Info__c,
> 01/01/2023 12:00))

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a number to a date or date time. You'd instead use the `DATETIMEVALUE` function:

```
(
  CUST_LAST_UPDATE - 
  Scheme_Referral__c.Scheme_Created_Date_Time__c
) - (
  BLANKVALUE(
    Scheme_Referral__c.Date_Broker_Response__c, 
    DATETIMEVALUE("2023-01-01 12:00:00")
  ) - (
  BLANKVALUE(
    Scheme_Referral__c.Date_Requested_Info__c, 
    DATETIMEVALUE("2023-01-01 12:00:00")
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for the reply, i have just tried to use this as above, but now i am getting the following error message; "Warning
Error when encoding row-level formula: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, received DateTime"